# How to extract the id of this string?

Tags: python, substring

For other Strings it works fine, but however getting the number isn't possible. Any suggestions?

```
text = "<:Valorant:946399790739099688><@&945697242994602054>"
start = text.find("<@&") + len("<@&")
end = text.find(">")
print(text[start:end])
```

Comment: "getting the number isn't possible" it isn't clear what your question is. Can you [edit] your question to include your expected output and how it's different from your current output?

Comment: your start is bigger than end because it  finds first occurrence of >

Comment: `d = '<@&'; text[text.find(d) + len(d):-1]`

Alternatives provided as answers are more flexible and useful generally speaking, but this would work with your initial approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a regex search to extract the first number

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "<:Valorant:946399790739099688><@&945697242994602054>"
>>> m = re.search(':(\d+)', text)
>>> m.group(1)
'946399790739099688'
```

if the id is the second number then instead you could use

```
>>> m = re.search('@&(\d+)', text)
>>> m.group(1)
'945697242994602054'
```

Answer (score 1):

If all your strings are of the form :

```py
"<:Valorant:number1><@&number2>"
```

you can retrieve the number using the following snippet:

```py
s = "<:Valorant:946399790739099688><@&945697242994602054>"
number1, number2 = map(int,s[11:-1].split("><@&"))
number1, number2
>>>> (946399790739099688, 945697242994602054)
```

Comment: Exactly the suggestion I was about to make! A split seems like the most appropriate approach if the format is static.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `split` to pull out things if the format is always the same like this:

```
text = "<:Valorant:946399790739099688><@&945697242994602054>"
id = text.split("><@&")[1].split(">")[0]
print(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixing split and re is also a decent option, and quite powerful when things get more complex. Just adding an option, lots of good options already provided. :)

```py
import re
text = "<:Valorant:946399790739099688><@&945697242994602054>"
o = re.split(r'[:>]|<@&', text)
print(o[1], o[2], o[4])
```

```
('Valorant', '946399790739099688', '945697242994602054')
```